# JQuery Regaining control over a external pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, slim-lang

As part of the payment process I must open a twitter-bootstrap modal by calling a form, this form in turn opens an external window to start the process with the banking channel guiding the user to enter their data and make the purchase.

The problem that I have, is that my page is hidden and I cannot resume control of the process, because the channel window is executing the

```
window.close();
```

command *(which I can not change or put my hands on it)* , so when I changed the initial

```
window.open("", "payment_method_page", "width=8, height=6");
```

for a modal, the channel page remains waiting and wanders despite the fact that internally I can see that the payment was successful made or had some failure. In the meantime Application is paused.

I already tried:

```
$('#paymentModal').modal('hide');
```

and:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#paymentModal').modal('hide')
}, 10000);
```

and even:

```
$('#paymentModal').on('click', 'a', function(event) {event.preventDefault(); window.open("", "payment_method_page", "width=800, height=600");});
```

,thinking that because my modal iniciated the process I could forced to close; but the external window is indifferent to this command.

How can I do to force the closure of a third-party window by JQuery?

**Javascript Inicial action**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#payment_button_id_copy').val(#{@order.payments.first.payment_button["codigoMedioPago"]})
      $('#payment_frequency_copy').val("#{@order.payments.first.payment_frequency}")
      //window.open("", "payment_method_page", "width=800, height=600"); 
      $('#paymentModal').modal('show');     
      $('#params_form').submit();
    });
```

**The Params_Form**

```
.hide
  = simple_form_for @order, url: main_app.payment_jump_path, html: { id: 'params_form'}, data: {target: "#paymentModal", toggle: "modal"} do
    - @order.available_payment_methods.each do |method|
      = hidden_field_tag "order[payments_attributes][][payment_method_id]", method.id, id: "payment_method_id_copy"
    = hidden_field_tag "order[payments_attributes][][payment_button_id]", nil, id: "payment_button_id_copy"
    = hidden_field_tag "order[payments_attributes][][payment_frequency]", nil, id: "payment_frequency_copy"
    button.submit-btn data-target="#paymentModal" data-toggle="modal" type="submit"
```

**The Javascript waiting for the external window to close**

```
 $(document).ready(function(event){
    start_at = +new Date();
    $.poll(10000, function(retry){
      $.get('/payments/check.json', function(response, status){
        if (response['completed'] == true) {
          $('#paymentModal').modal('hide');
          $('.payment-message-waiting').hide();
          $('.payment-message-success').removeClass('hide');
          $('form#checkout_form_payment_button').submit();
        } else {
          if (response['failed'] == true) {
            $('.payment-message-waiting').hide();
            $('.payment-message-error').removeClass('hide')
          } else {
            retry_at = +new Date();

            delta = retry_at-start_at

            // 5 min => 300000 miliseconds => 5 * 60 * 1000
            if ( delta > 300000 ){
              window.location = '/content/session-expired';
            } else {
              retry();
            }
          }
        }
      })
    })

    $.poll(5000, function(retry) {
      $.get('/payments/check_payment_presence.js', function(response, status){
        var payment_info = document.getElementById('payment-info').hasChildNodes();
        if(!payment_info) {
          retry();
        }
      })
    })
  });
```

Comment: Read the payment gateway notification carefully. You'll find that it has a *"response URL"* at which it sends a response request for each processed payment (including the failed ones). You'll also find that the response structure is well documented. What you need to do is setup your server (backend) to process all requests from the payment gateway. But they two are totally different (separated) processes. You probably want to use a database in which you store all the gateway requests (as the user leaves) and complete them once you get the result from the gateway, via the response URL.

Comment: Note the request from the gateway is not part of the user journey. The user, once they ended the payment, can be returned on your server to a "Thank you" page, but that's not related to the response URL, which might come many minutes later (some payment gateways take up to 30 minutes to process payments). Also note you might get more than one response for each payment request, as the status of the request changes. All gateways document this fairly well. Last, but not least, don't use [SO] for advice on payment practices. The only authority is the technical staff of the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I implemented (kudos to @hermes_sandoval for the help) of was forcing the other page to open in a Iframe inside the modal, in that way my the user always in control if the service takes to long to process.

```
javascript:
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#payment_button_id_copy').val(#{@order.payments.first.payment_button["codigoMedioPago"]})
    $('#payment_frequency_copy').val("#{@order.payments.first.payment_frequency}")
    $('#iframeRedirect').html('');
    var iframe = "<iframe name='payment_method_page'  style='height: 660px;'/>";
    $('#iframeRedirect').append(iframe);
    $('#paymentModal').modal('show');
    $('#params_form').submit();
  });
```